# One category showing wrong sidebar layered navigation

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.4, layered-navigation

I am using Porto theme, I upgraded Magento 2.2.4 to Magento 2.4.2, every thing working fine but there are 1 problem, all category page using app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml for sidebar layered navigation and all filters working (price, manufacturer, color).
But one of the category using /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/navigation/left.phtml for sidebar layered navigation there are categories in list but not other filters (price, manufacturer, color)

My question is why only one category not calling Porto theme layer/view.phtml and calling Magento vendor navigation/left.phtml

please help me.

Below image is actual working image after upgrade and works with all categories:
[image]

Below image is wrong layered navigation image which call automatically at only one category.
[image]

Comment: make sure "Is Anchor"'s value set same as all other categories for this category.

Comment: Thanks @GohilRajesh, this works, all others category "Is Anchor" was Yes but one category "Is Anchor" was No and that was creating problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure "Is Anchor"'s value set same as all other categories for this category.

Because based on that it serve layout `catalog_category_view_type_default` and  `catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children`